# Display recently submitted articles / pictures on my site

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I'm attempting to have users submit a motivational piece or picture to my page to be displayed on the home page and subsequent pages (ie. domain.com/page/2), ordered by most recent, with each page displaying 15 pieces each.

I would also like to have it possible to create an individual page from every given image / piece so users may comment on it, having gotten to the individual page from a link from the article on the main page, automatically generated and appended to each of the 15 pieces. Similar to http://icanhas.cheezburger.com/ with their individual pages for images.

What sort of method ought I be taking to achieve this result?
I've looked at having a simple template, with comments, which submitted pieces from users would be applied to create individual pages, yet I'm unsure about how have most recent on the home page (and subsequent pages), and is a php template the right idea anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data about the file in a database along with a datetime column for when it was inserted, which will easily let you query for data in the last week/day/hour/minute etc.

On that note, don't store the actual *file* in the database, just the meta information on it such as the user who submitted, ID, tags and the like.

Then use a query like this (mysql formatting):

```
select id, fileName from yourTable where dateColumn>date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
```

which will return any images where DateColumn is updated to less than 24 hours from now.

Armed with this data available to you, you can create a script that uses one bit of code to show any of these to a user. You can use pagination to split the results up onto different pages - or you can drop the `dateColumn>date_sub()` and simply order by the DateTime so that your one script can take viewers from the newest image all the way through to the final image in your database.

Edit: To split the results into a set, assume you are using the following query:

```
select
    col1,
    col2
from
    yourTable
order by
    dateColumn desc;
```

The query would return the ENTIRE table, but if you just want the newest 10 records, you can use a limit clause in it:

```
select
    col1,
    col2
from
    yourTable
order by
    dateColumn desc
limit 0,10;
```

The syntax for limit is (limit: [number of rows to skip], [number of rows to return]). So on the next page use:

```
limit 10,10
```

which then brings the next 10 records and so on.

Comment: Ahh, that's a huge quantity of help, thanks for that. I'm not entirely sure about how to go about pagination; is that easily done?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million! That will help to no end. Cheers.